# How to resolve error "Using the generic type 'List<T>' requires 1 type argument"?

Tags: c#

I am getting the following error and have tried looking at various post here on SO but can't find a solution the the problem I am experiencing:

Thi is my code I have (FYI this is to get the datepicker to work in Chrome using ReportViewer) and the link where this code is:  https://rajbandi.net/2012/04/03/fixing-ssrs-report-viewer-control-date-picker-in-google-chrome/

Here is the code:

```
protected void OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs ex)
{
    base.OnPreRender(ex);
    DatePickers.Value = String.Join(",", (new List(GetDateParameters()).ToArray()));

}
private IEnumerable GetDateParameters()
{
    foreach (ReportParameterInfo info in ReportViewer2.ServerReport.GetParameters())
    {
        if (info.DataType == ParameterDataType.DateTime)
        {
            yield return string.Format("[{0}]", info.Prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error under `List`

Thanks

Comment: Without trying it, you should be able to simply change it to: `String.Join(",", GetDateParameters()))`. No need to create a `List`. You might also need to change the signature of `GetDateParameters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a relatively recent version of .NET, just change `GetDateParameters` to return an `IEnumerable<string>` and you can get rid of some of that other stuff:

```
protected void OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs ex)
{
    base.OnPreRender(ex);
    DatePickers.Value = String.Join(",", GetDateParameters());

}
private IEnumerable<string> GetDateParameters()
{
    foreach (ReportParameterInfo info in ReportViewer2.ServerReport.GetParameters())
    {
        if (info.DataType == ParameterDataType.DateTime)
        {
            yield return string.Format("[{0}]", info.Prompt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `new List()`, but you can create a `new List<string>()` (GetDateParameters should also return `IEnumerable<string>`) .